# LINQ: Search multiple fields of a List of objects where fields can be null

Tags: c#, linq, null-conditional-operator

I am trying to filter a list of objects using a multi field search box. It takes the text, then applies the search to the list. However, address 2 and 3 could potentially be blank (and in this case null in the 
objects the list is made up of) depending on the address submitted.

I have the following expression.

```
Properties.Where(x => x.Address1.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text) 
                  || x.Address2.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text) 
                  || x.Address3.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text))
          .ToList();
```

Its currently throwing an exception because it, quite rightly so, can't search a null field.

How can i get it to skip or ignore null fields? Can it be done in a single expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some null check like this

```
(x?.Address1?.ToLower()??"").Contains(senderElement?.Text??"")
```

Comment: Wonderful and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
 Properties.Where(x => (x.Address1 != null && x.Address1.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text)) 
              || (x.Address2 != null && x.Address2.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text)) 
              || (x.Address3 != null && x.Address3.ToLower().Contains(senderElement.Text)))
      .ToList();
```

This will check null value as well

Comment: i think that would still throw the same error. The problem is the second part cant be done

Comment: @Takarii: It will not throw error. & Operator is short circuit. If first condition is false, it will not check the next.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of that. I assumed it would try and evaluate both, then decide